# Android - Setting duration on androids CamcorderProfile is not being used

Tags: android, video-capture

Currently I am trying to set a max duration on a CamcorderProfile for android that will be used by a media recorder.  Based off of the documentation if I set the duration attribute to an int in seconds that should work.  Some reason though it isn't respected.

```
CamcorderProfile baseProfile = mCameraWrapper.getBaseRecordingProfile();
baseProfile.duration = 5;
recorder.setProfile(baseProfile);
```

In this case the recorder should stop recording after 5 seconds but never does, it will only work if I set the setting on the recorder's setMaxDuration.

Any idea what the profile's duration setting is for if it isn't being used for max duration of the video?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Those are read only attributes of the camcoder application itself, they arent necessarly used by the media recorder.

Infact if you take a look here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#MediaRecorder.setProfile%28android.media.CamcorderProfile%29

you can see that the duration is not used, instead you can use setMaxDuration:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxDuration(int)

to do that.